# get datasource connection in websphere liberty

Tags: websphere-liberty

I am able to set datasource in websphere liberty and validated it through REST API .
How to get the datasource connection in java code .I am trying this way

```
InitialContext please = new InitialContext();
```

DataSource ds = (DataSource)please.lookup("jdbc/aces2/testdatasource");
Connection connection = ds.getConnection();

and getting error below. Please help me resolve this

```
com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory (initialization failure) 
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializationAlreadyFailed(J9VMInternals.java:98)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:-2)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:83)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
at
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using `new InitialContext();` not `new InitialContext(properties)`? As this class `com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory` is used in WebSphere traditional, not LIberty.
And instead of using direct lookup, I'd suggest to use annotation in your class like: `@Resource(jndiName="/jdbc/aces2/estdatasource") Datasource ds;`

Answer (score 0):

JNDI lookups in Liberty are provided by the `jndi-1.0` feature. Trying adding this feature to your server.xml and see if that solves the problem.  For example,

```
<server>
  <featureManager>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.2</feature>
    ... other features
  </featureManager>

  ...
</server>
```

Comment: I believe when doing a direct lookup like this don't you need to use the fully qualified name `DataSource ds = (DataSource)please.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/aces2/testdatasource");`

Comment: "Don't need to"?  Don't you mean, "need to"?

Comment: But my code throws exception at initial context stage itself